# Request Query String in Aspx.Page not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

Want to set query string value to hidden field in aspx page. My code is like below :

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden" Value='<%= Request.QueryString["id"]%>' />
```

Am aware this can be achieved using jquery/ Javascript & also server side programming. But wonder why it wont work. The value of hidden filed am getting is `<%= Request.QueryString["id"]%>` rather than the actual value.

Comment: In code behind Page_Load method: `hidden.Value = Request.QueryString["id"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot mix `runat=server` with `<%= %>`.

You can use: `<%# %>` syntax if you are in a databound control, or you can call `DataBind()` on the control from code-behind or inline server script.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden" Value='<%# Request.QueryString["id"]%>' />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
        hidden.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codes written between <%= %> intended to use in html tags, since you are passing your parameter in querystring if you need to keep it somewhere in your page try this

```
<div runat="server" style="visibility:hidden;" id="hiddenfield">
  <%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>
</div>
```

you can reach to hiddenfield value in serverside by hiddenfield.innerHTML property, hope it will help you